# Convert single dimensional Array to DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a single dimensional `Array` output (as shown below) and need to be converted to `DataFrame`.

```
x = rand(4)
4-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.951252
 0.936421
 0.773268
 0.207913

p = convert(DataFrame, x) // Why this doesn't work ?
```

This results in:

> MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an
>   object of type DataFrames.DataFrame This may have arisen from a call
>   to the constructor DataFrames.DataFrame(...), since type constructors
>   fall back to convert methods.

Why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that DataFrame needs column name. You could use for example this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(column_name = x)
4×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ column_name │
├─────┼─────────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.349747    │
│ 2   │ 0.718652    │
│ 3   │ 0.0984634   │
│ 4   │ 0.553987    │
```

If you have problem with julia then good start is to use help:

```
julia>?DataFrame
```

if you press ? as first character prompt is changed to

```
help?> DataFrame
```

after pressing enter you could see help in this case with examples.

Maybe some tutorial. For example [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/DataFrames) could help too.